# How do I open the Share Intent Dialog with Adobe AIr with navigateToURL

Tags: android, android-intent, air, adobe, navigatetourl

```
intent:#Intent;action=android.intent.action.SEND;type=text/plain;launchFlags=0x1;S.android.intent.extra.TEXT="+encodeURIComponent(socialShareEvent.message)+";S.android.intent.extra.SUBJECT="+encodeURIComponent(socialShareEvent.subject)+";end
```

Throws a document not supported error!?

Comment: I don't think it's possible with navigateToURL but you can launch the share intent dialog with this free Air ANE: http://www.smallscreendesign.com/2011/09/29/air-native-extensions-rock/